# Passing an array to another view SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to pass an array to another view. I want to pass the array simulation to operating conditions view.

```
@State var simulation = [Any]()
```

I know you can not see all the code but below is where if a button is pressed to show the operating conditions view and pass in an array after the array is loaded with data I have checked to make sure Simulation array does have values in it before passing and it does.

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showingOperatingConditions) {
            OperatingConditionsView(threats: simulation)
        }
```

Here is the operating conditions view where threats is declared. For some reason, the array is empty every time I load the view. Can anybody help?

```
struct OperatingConditionsView: View {


    @State public var threats = [Any]()

}
```

Comment: Perhaps declare the simulation @ State and then define it in the sheet view as @ binding and then pass it with $simulation?

Comment: Change from `@State` to @Binding if you are going to change the array otherwise just remove `@State`. Off topic but why is the array declared as [Any]?

Comment: because the array is a json object @JoakimDanielson

Comment: @sheldor it is giving me errors when I change this.. I may be doing it wrong. Can you reply with a visual answer?

Comment: Don’t know if it is allowed here, but can I get an upvote for the reply please, because I really need this for the next step, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments said, you want to change `OperatingConditionsView`'s `threats` into a `@Binding`. You'll then need to pass in `$simulation` with a `$` (gets its Binding).

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showingOperatingConditions) {
    OperatingConditionsView(threats: $simulation) /// need a $ here
}
```

```
struct OperatingConditionsView: View {
    @Binding public var threats: [Any] /// don't initialize with default value
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't need changes in `threats` to auto-update `simulation`, you can go with a plain, non-binding property as [@Joakim Danielson's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67559839/passing-an-array-to-another-view-swiftui/67560079#comment119414154_67559839) said.

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showingOperatingConditions) {
    OperatingConditionsView(threats: simulation)
}
```

```
struct OperatingConditionsView: View {
    public var threats: [Any]
}
```